# C++ using AND operator in integer expression

Tags: c++, loops, expression

I'm reading some source code for designing an Octree and found this in the code. I have removed some elements for simplication, but can anyone explain what `i&4` is supposed to evaluate to?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    float j = i&4 ? .5f : -.5f;
}
```

Comment: Nope, just a small error in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is the `bitwise AND Operator`.

It just does a bitwise operation of the value stored in `i AND 0x4`.

It exactly just isolates the third bit as 2^2 = 4.

Your expression in the loop checks if third bit is set in i and assigns to j (which must be a float!) 0.5 or if not set -0.5

Comment: Minor nitpick: that's not the second bit, that's the third bit (bit 0 is the first bit).

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator in this case is a bitwise AND. Since the second operand is 4, a power of 2, it evaluates to 4 when `i` has its second least-significant bit set, and to 0 otherwise.

The `for` loop takes `i` from 0 to 7, inclusive. Consider bit representations of `i` in this range:

```
0000 - 0
0001 - 1
0010 - 2
0011 - 3
0100 - 4
0101 - 5
0110 - 6
0111 - 7
 ^
 |
This bit determines the result of i & 4
```

Therefore, the end result of the conditional is as follows: if the second bit is set (i.e. when `i` is 4, 5, 6, or 7), the result is `0.5f`; otherwise, it is `-0.5f`.

For the given range of values, this expression can be rewritten as

```
float j = (i >= 4) ? .5f : -.5f;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it may evaluate the bitwise and operation of i and 4 (100), so any number which has a '1' in its third bit will be evaluted to true, otherwise false.

Ex: 
5 (101) & 4 (100) = 100 (4) which is different from 0 so its true
8 (1000) & 4 (100) = 0000 (0) which is false

Answer (score 0):

`i & 4` just evaluate to true when the value-4 bit is set. In your case this only happens in the second half of the loop. So the code could actually be rewritten:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    float j = -.5f;
}

for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
{
    float j = .5f;
}
```